# next fire date in UIlocalNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

Hi All
I have created a UILocalNotification....& when i print it

```
NSLog(@"Notification %@",self.notification)
```

it gives

```
Notification <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x6f45440>
{fire date = 2010-10-22 00:09:00 -0700, time zone = America/Vancouver (PDT) offset -25200
(Daylight), repeat interval = 64, **next fire date** = 2010-10-22 00:10:00 -0700}
```

But I want to access the next fire date of this Notification how can i get this value?
Please any help for this.

Answer (score 1):

`UILocalNotification` has a [fireDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW2) property that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access it directly as a property, because it is calculated based on fireDate and repeatInterval.

Here is the answer to your question

[How to grab the NEXT fire date from a UILocalNotification object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301184/how-to-grab-the-next-fire-date-from-a-uilocalnotification-object)

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];    
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:self.localNotification.repeatInterval 

fromDate:self.localNotification.fireDate];

NSDate *nextFireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```