# Find out last fired UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm working on an Alarm app for iOS which uses UILocalNotifications. So far so good, until somebody came up with the idea of showing a route from where the user is to where he wants to go.

For this I thought I could maybe get the last fired UILocalNotification ( All of them have repeatInterval set as weekly or daily).

Here is where the whole trouble comes in, since the fireDate is the first time I scheduled them: This is my scenario:

```
        UILocalNotification* ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        ln.fireDate = date; // For instance 07/19/2014 10:00:00 (Saturday)
        ln.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;            
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:ln];

        UILocalNotification* ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        ln.fireDate = date; // For instance 07/17/2014 11:00:00 (Thursday)
        ln.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;            
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:ln];
```

Let picture this:

Next Thursday (07/24/2014 11:00:01) I want to know that the last fired UILocalNotification was the second one that only repeats on Thursdays and the next day I want the first one since it repeats daily.

I've tried to sort by date all LocalNotifications with no success.

Has anyone ever faced a situation akin to it before?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS will discard a local notification after it fires even if it is scheduled to repeat itself via the `repeatInterval` property.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications` actually returns all notifications that are scheduled to be fired in the **future**. <s>So their `fireDate` will be set to  a date in the future.</s>

After further investigation, it seems that the `fireDate` is always set to the original value specified when the notification was created. However, the next fire date, a calculated value, will be in the future. To see this value simply run `po yourNotificationObj` in the debugger and you will see the following type of output, which includes the next fire date:

> {fire date = Saturday, July
>   26, 2014 at 1:42:50 PM Eastern Daylight Time, time zone = (null),
>   repeat interval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit, repeat count =
>   UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, **next fire date** = Saturday,
>   July 26, 2014 at 1:43:50 PM Eastern Daylight Time, user info = (null)}

How do you calculate the next fire date? Please see the following code taken from [How to grab the NEXT fire date from a UILocalNotification object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301184/how-to-grab-the-next-fire-date-from-a-uilocalnotification-object):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = localNotif.repeatCalendar;
if (!calendar) {
  calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
}

NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
// If you use some other repeat interval you would have to change the code accordingly. 
// If you were to use NSMonthCalendarUnit you would have 
// to use `components.month = 1' instead
components.day = 1;
NSDate *nextFireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:localnotif.fireDate options:0];
```

If you want to remember the last fired local notification then you must build that logic into your app and save the required information. For example, you could do the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotification) {
        [self saveLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [self saveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)saveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    // save information about the last fired local notification on disk
}

- (UILocalNotification *)lastFiredLocalNotification
{
    // read the information stored on disk by the saveLocalNotification: method
    // and recreate the notification. I'm just saying recreate the notification
    // because I don't know what exactly you're trying to do. You 
    // can return anything you want here
}
```

Using the above setup, you can call the `lastFiredLocalNotification` method whenever you need it.

Answer (score 2):

iOS discards local notifications after they're fired. You're responsible for maintaining this information in some other way if you need the information later.

If you want, you can inspect `[UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications.firstObject` to see the next one that's scheduled, then use that information to determine from your own data model which was before it.

Comment: I've inspected them and it seems like iOS only discards notification that have not repeatInterval set. In my scenario all local notifications have it set since I could list all of them after they fired.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Sid's answer and some code snippets from SO I could come up with this solution which  calculates the last fired date for all local notifications without writing it to a file or even to a database. ( Although writing it somewhere isn't a bad idea )

**Header**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILocalNotification (LastFireDate)

- (NSDate *)lastFireDateBeforeDate:(NSDate *)afterDate;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
#import "UILocalNotification+LastFireDate.h"

@implementation UILocalNotification (LastFireDate)

- (NSDate *)lastFireDateBeforeDate:(NSDate *)afterDate
{
    // Check if fire date is in the future:
    if ([afterDate compare:self.fireDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];

    // The notification can have its own calendar, but the default is the current calendar:
    NSCalendar *cal = self.repeatCalendar;
    if (cal == nil)
        cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Number of repeat intervals between fire date and the reference date:
    NSDateComponents *difference = [cal components:self.repeatInterval
                                          fromDate:self.fireDate
                                            toDate:afterDate
                                           options:0];

    // Add this number of repeat intervals to the initial fire date:
    NSDate *lastFireDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:difference
                                                toDate:self.fireDate
                                               options:0];

    // If necessary, subtract one interval:
    if ([lastFireDate compare:afterDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        switch (self.repeatInterval) {
            case NSWeekCalendarUnit:
                difference.week--;
                break;
            case NSDayCalendarUnit:
                difference.day--;
                break;
            case NSHourCalendarUnit:
                difference.hour--;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        lastFireDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:difference
                                            toDate:self.fireDate
                                           options:0];
    }
    return lastFireDate;
}


@end
```

**Usage**

```
    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSArray* arrayNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

    if([arrayNotifications count])
    {
        NSArray *sorted = [arrayNotifications sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UILocalNotification *obj1, UILocalNotification *obj2) {
            NSDate *next1 = [obj1 lastFireDateBeforeDate:date];
            NSDate *next2 = [obj2 lastFireDateBeforeDate:date];
            return [next1 compare:next2];
        }];

        UILocalNotification* lastLocalNotification = [sorted lastObject];
        NSLog(@"%s %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[lastLocalNotification lastFireDateBeforeDate:date]);
    }
```

Hope it helps someone who is facing the same issue

Cheers

Comment: +1. Thanks for posting your solution. It's really helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @PauloMiguelAlmeida please can you modify this code according to timezone, I have specified defaultTimeZone in my UILocalNotification and I am calculating date by changing timezone but I am getting wrong result, please help me modifying your code according to defaultTimeZone. Thank you

Comment: @S.J It shouldn't actually matter which timezone you're using as long as you're using the same one on both UILocationNotification and this category method.